# A question about monomial orderings.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is a question in Ideals, Varieties and Algorithms by Cox, Little, Oshea.

Let $>$ be any monomial ordering. Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}^n$. Show that $\alpha \ge 0$.

I don't understand the question. $\alpha$ is a vector and $0$ is a scalar. What are they asking me to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think in $\alpha>0$, $0$ is an $n$-tuple of $0$s in $\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}^n$.  This would correspond to a constant monomial.  So I think the problem is asking you to show that for every monomial ordering, any monomial is greater than or equal to the monomial $x_1^0 x_2^0 \cdots x_n^0=1$ (the monomial that gives you constant terms).